# Returning Optional Values based on Database Value

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement

I'm trying to return a SVG based on the value `1,2 or 3` from my database column called `foo_options`.

- IF 1 return Green SVG
- IF 2 return Orange SVG
- IF 3 return Red SVG

`foo_options` has the value of 3 in the database. So the SVG should be Red.

**Here is what I have in my Model:**

```
    public function getOptionValueAttribute(){
        if ('1') {
            return '<svg>Green</svg>';
        }elseif ('2') {
            return '<svg>Orange</svg>';
        }elseif ('3') {
            return '<svg>Red</svg>';
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }
```

**Then my logic is:**

```
if($bar->barDetail->some_options = '1' || $bar->barDetail->some_options = '2' || $bar->barDetail->some_options = '3')
{
    dd($bar->barDetail->optionValue);
}
```

With the above logic, GREEN (1) is always returned.

Any help to return Red would be much appreciated.

Comment: because the string `'1'` is `true` logically .... your first if statement is always `true` ... you are not actually checking anything in that accessor

Comment: @lagbox even if I do `if (1)` .. still returns Green.

Comment: because `1 == true` ...      you are saying  `if(true)`

Comment: AH. Duh.. Okay so how can I fix this. Rather using INT in the DB, Use a String fro the value? One, Two, Three

Comment: you are not actually checking anything .. what value do you think you are checking? you are not comparing anything to do an evaluation

Comment: If `some_options` = 1,2,3 return `optionValue` based on the `some_options` value

Comment: so   `if ($some_option == '1')` ?

Comment: yes. `if ($some_option == '1')` return `optionValue 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *getOptionValueAttribute* function is not doing any checks inside. You pass the string *'1'* to the *if* operator and *if* works with boolean. A non empty string is always converted to true and therefore you always return green.

What I assume that you are trying to do is that you wish to check the value of some variable and return different results if it is 1, 2 or 3. Therefore I would think that you will need to pass that variable as input for the function and than compare the value to it:

```
public function getOptionValueAttribute($option){
    if ($option == 1) {
        return '<svg>Green</svg>';
    }elseif ($option == 2) {
        return '<svg>Orange</svg>';
    }elseif ($option == 3) {
        return '<svg>Red</svg>';
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

That way if you call the function like this (for example) you will get the Red:

```
getOptionValueAttribute(3);
```

If you insist on working with strings, just add the quotes around the numbers.

I don't know what the second code that you shown above is trying to explain. I don't get that logic and how it is related to the function at all. Note that the comparison operator is == or ===, not just =.

Comment: The second code I'm trying to replicate what I'd be doing in the view.

Comment: But now realize this is incorrect. Your public function fix was perfect. In the View I call it like this and all works great. `{!! $home->homeDetail->optionValue($home->homeDetail->some_options) !!}` Thank you for the help, much appreciated!